# Renorming of $C[0,1]$ for a strictly convex dual

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of all Real valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the usual supremum norm. Does there exist an equivalent renorming on $C[0,1]$ such that the corresponding dual norm is strictly convex?

Comment: The dual of every separabel Banach space has an eqivalent strictly convex norm, but I understand that this is not you question.

Comment: Thank you Jochen for pointing out. I was a bit confused about Hahn-Banach smoothness and smoothness. A Banach space $X$ is said to be Hahn-Banach smooth if every $x^*\in X^*$ has unique norm preserving extension to $X^{**}$. Similarly a weaker version of this property can also be defined for the norm attaining functionals. If $X^*$ is strictly convex then any subspace of $X$ is Hahn-Banach smooth BUT this property does not imply (weakly) Hahn-Banach smoothness of $X$.

Comment: My earlier question can be reformulated as follows. Does there exist an equivalent renorming on $C[0,1]$ which makes it (weakly) Hahn-Banach smooth?  Probably the answer to this problem is 'No' because the dual of any weakly Hahn-Banach smooth space has RNP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One typically equivalently renorms a Banach space $Y$ to be strictly convex by finding an injective operator $S$ from $Y$ into some strictly convex space $Z$ and defining the new norm on $Y$ by $\|y\| +\|Sy\|$. When $Y$ and $Z$ are dual spaces and $S$ is weak$^*$ to weak$^*$ continuous, the new norm is a dual norm (the new unit ball of $X^*$ is weak$^*$ closed because $T^*$ is weak$^*$ continuous).

So let $X$ be any separable space and take an operator $T:\ell^2 \to X$ that has dense range. Renorm $X^*$ by
$!F! := \| F \|_{X^*} + \|T^*F\|_2$.

Comment: Bill, your exclamation marks would have surely won a contest for the funniest norm symbol, if only there were one! :-)

Comment: @TomaszKania. I think I first saw $! \cdot !$
 in my undergraduate days when I took a course in functional analysis from Wilansky's book.