# Conditions that make a dual space strictly convex

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

We know that a normed space $X$ is said to be strictly convex if

$\Vert tx+(1-t)y\Vert<1$, $\forall t\in(0,1)$, $\forall x,y\in X$ with $\Vert x\Vert=\Vert y\Vert=1$ and $x\neq y$.

For example if $X$ is a Hilbert space or $X=L^p(\Omega)$ with $1<p<\infty$, then $X^{\ast}$ (the dual space of $X$) is strictly covex.

My question is that which properties a normed space $X$ should have to achive a strictly convex dual space $X^{\ast}$?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/364390/454

Comment: Take a look at Tacon, D. G.
The conjugate of a smooth Banach space.
Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 2 (1970), 415–425.

Answer (score 2):

One answer to your question is given here: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-02/S0002-9939-1958-0093696-3/S0002-9939-1958-0093696-3.pdf